# Maven: Get Compilation error case in surefire-reports

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm running mvn test, and based on the generated xml results file, i'm preparing the results summary.

Here now i'm only able to handle right or wrong testcases.

and if any issue in the code, i'm getting the compilation error in the `mvn test`

Can we log the compilation errors as well in the surefire-reports ?

**Outcome expected:** include the compilation error case in the below result itself.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldApplicationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.666 s - in com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldApplicationTests
```

Comment: No you can not log them in test reportings. The execution of tests requires compilable tests ...If you can not compile your tests you can't even executed them... that does not make sense... Maybe you can elaborate more in detail what your problem is ...

Comment: Maybe change question to : `How to check build failure in Jenkins?`

Comment: @khmarbaise I need to parse the above-given results file and give aggregated results for tests, so if one test case failed with a compilation error, what abt other cases which can pass if the compilation error test not there

Comment: Do you use some kind of CI solution like Jenkins or alike? That would be the best place to handle that... apart from that it will be working out of the box in Jenkins..